# Can't access phpmyadmin - Ubuntu MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I can't access my phpmyadmin.

[image]

I'm very sure of my password because I can access it via terminal:

[image]

Comment: Try clearing cache/cookies. Restart PHP.

Comment: how? Clean my browser? Or via terminal?

Comment: Yes, he means clearing the cache/cookies of your browser.

Comment: I'm done. I also used other browser but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config.inc.php` for phpMyAdmin and verify that the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` field is actually set to 'localhost'. This seems the most likely problem. Additionally, the message about the controluser can be resolved by commenting out the line in config.inc.php that references a controluser and controlpass. It is an administrative user that phpMyAdmin uses for some advanced features; once you have your log in working properly you can worry about creating it if you desire.

Comment: where i can find config.inc.php?

Comment: Normally it's in the phpMyAdmin folder of your web root (which is likely `/var/www/`), but if you installed via the package manager, then it's probably `/etc/phpmyadmin/`